# Is there gitg for windows?

Tags: windows, gitg

I have googled but it seems Gitg doesn't have a Win32 port. Isn't that gitg is a Gtk application? I feel like it would not be too hard to compile and run it under win32.

Comment: if you really want a native Git application for Windows check out GitExtensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find it a bit hard to port it. Here's what the author has to say about the portability of gitg ([source](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Version-Control/gitg-49042.shtml)):

> gitg is a git repository viewer targeting GTK+ and GNOME. One of its
>   main objectives is to provide a more unified user experience for git
>   frontends across multiple desktops. It does this not be writing a
>   cross-platform application, but by close collaboration with similar
>   clients for other operating systems (like GitX for OS X).

I'm sure it's still doable. But it's definitely up to someone else to do it. So you shouldn't probably expect a port to windows anytime soon. Alternatively you can always run it from Windows with tools such as:

- [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer), or
- [andLinux](http://www.andlinux.org/)

Answer (score 8):

There is now an installer available for gitg on windows

http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win64/gitg/